# Оборот, начинающийся словами "пускай и"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужно ли ставить запятую:

> За время наших, пускай и непродолжительных(,) похождений по лагерю
>   окружавшие нас тени ощутимо удлинились.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оборот обособляется:

**За время наших, пускай и непродолжительных, похождений по лагерю окружавшие нас тени ощутимо удлинились.**

Но это **не уточняющий оборот** (здесь нет сужения значения), а пояснительный (скорее даже присоединительный, с дополнительной информацией).

Объяснение

1) ***Наши непродолжительные похождения:*** отношения между притяжательным местоимением и прилагательным **неоднородные**, их можно преобразовать (при наличии союза ***пусть***) только в **пояснительные** (выделение запятыми с обеих сторон).

2) **В общем же случае** уступительный союз ***пусть*** допускает **как однородные** (одна запятая), **так и пояснительные** (две запятые) отношения .

**Примеры**:

...надо использовать **надежные, пусть и дорогие,** сетевые устройства, правильно настраивать сеть..[«Эксперт», 2013]

...появился собственник, который держался за **надежный, пусть и не высокорентабельный** бизнес...[Евгений Огородников. // «Эксперт», 2015]

...он бы хорошо справлялся с честно созданными, **пусть и предельными** трудностями. [ // «Русский репортер», 2015]

Ну а пока он спит у полузатухшего костерка, который серым дымком льнёт к нему, отжимая **пусть и редких, но надоедливых** комаров. [Виктор Астафьев. Затеси (1999) // «Новый Мир», 2000]

Answer (score 2):

Здесь уточняющее определение со значением "размера", присоединённое подчинительным союзом и неоднородное по отношению к предшествующему (наших). Поэтому требуется обособление (вторая запятая нужна). В тексте вместо "пускай" (разг.) предпочтительно "пусть".

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118

(см. § 22, п.4)